# Find matrix size from one dimensional array for get()

Tags: arrays, algorithm, matrix

I have a matrix that is shaped like an S and that is at least of size 5*5. It it represented in a one dimensional array by putting the first line, then the middle line, then the last line and at last the numbers on the first and last column.

As an example, the following matrix:

```
1  2  3  4  5
6  0  0  0  0
7  8  9  10 11 
0  0  0  0  12
13 14 15 16 17
```

would be represented in this array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,6,12]
```

The point is I want to write a get(i,j) function that gets the right number from the one dimensional array, for example get(1,0) would give me 6. And for that I need to know the matrix size. However I can't find a way to get it from the one dimensional array.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can figure out what case we have based on the coordinate:

```
if(i == 0) //first row
    return array[j];
else if(i == (size - 1) / 2) //middle row
    return array[size + j];
else if(i == size - 1) //last row
    return array[2 * size + j];
else if(j == 0 && i < (size - 1) / 2) //first column
    return array[3 * size + i - 1);
else if(j == size - 1 && i > (size - 1) / 2) //last column
    return array[3 * size + (size - 3) / 2 + i - (size - 1) / 2];
else
    return 0;
```

Comment: Right that's the part that i managed to do but the problem is that i don't know size, and i have to find it from the one dimensional array.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Missed that part. We get `array length = 3 * size + 2 * (size - 3)/2`. Solving for `size` gives us `size = (3 + array length) / 4`.